# How can we implement Pagination for Mongodb Collection using mongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query

I'm a noob in mongoDb i need to implement Pagination for any specific Collection for instance say

I have a Collection Foo and i have a Fucntion that returns all the records from the Foo collection

```
public List<Foo> getFoo(){

}
```

But i need to fetch records from the Foo by implementing pagination how can i achieve this by using mongoTemplate Spring data mongodb?

Answer (score 14):

For general pagination you can use the `.skip()` and `.limit()` modifiers on the Query object which you can pass in as arguments to your method:

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("a").is("b"));
    query.skip(10);
    query.limit(10);

    List<Foo> results = mongoOperation.find(query, Foo);
```

With `.skip()` being how may results to go past and `.limit()` being the page size to return.

So derive an instance of MongoOperations from MongoTemplate and use a standard `.find()` operation from there.

Skip and limit is not the most performant option though, try to store last seen values on a natural index like `_id` where possible and use range queries to avoid "skipping" through 1000's of results.

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").gt(lastSeen));
    query.limit(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide skip and limit to the query you are using, and this should help doing pagination.
Take a look at method [find](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#find(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,%20java.lang.Class)) in MongoTemplate class.

Your method should look like this:

```
public List<Foo> getFoo(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {...}
```